# Which Is Faster $variable[] or array_push($variable, $newValue)?

Tags: php, arrays, operators

Which is faster when adding variables to an array?

1. $variable[] = $newValue;
2. array_push($variable,$newValue);

and please mention the difference between the two if any.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Both are blazing fast and the difference is negligible. Stop overoptimising your code. Focus on real problems.

Comment: What happenned when you tested it?

Comment: I've had instances where array_push didn't work for multidimensional array but the direct assignment did. So, unless you are working with a very large array I say go with whichever you feel comfortable with (or works) !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#53289

> Empy bracket doesn't check if a
>   variable is an array first as
>   array_push does.  If array_push finds
>   that a variable isn't an array it
>   prints a Warning message if E_ALL
>   error reporting is on.
>
> So array_push is safer than [], until
>   further this is changed by the PHP
>   developers.

`$variable[]` seems to be  a lot faster:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#83388

**However** if you're adding multiple values per iteration `array_push()` is faster:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#84959

But please remember that **pre-optimization** is the root of all evil. Use whatever you feel more comfortable with, and when you have a performance issue, use a profiler and do some benchmarking.

Answer (score 8):

Stop doing weird things and take profiler to get real bottleneck.

ps: there is no difference.

pps: here is typical algo:

1. Does the application speed satisfy you? If no - step 2, if yes - step 6
2. Take the profiler
3. Find the **slowest** part
4. Optimize it so it become faster
5. Go to step 1
6. Get some beer